# Dirichlet distribution plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dirichlet-distribution

I want to plot $15$ random draws of  Dirichlet distribution with $\alpha = 1$ and dimension $n=10$ in R.

```
require(MCMCpack)
alpha <- 1
draws <- 15
dimen <- 10
x <- rdirichlet(draws, rep(alpha, dimen))
```

I want an output similar to the following image. This image is from Prof. David Blei's [Topic Modeling tutorial](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/kdd-tutorial.pdf) at KDD 2011. I think it has been done using ggplot2 but I don't know how to generate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to put the data into a sensible form for `ggplot2`:

```
dat <- data.frame(item=factor(rep(1:10,15)), 
                  draw=factor(rep(1:15,each=10)), 
                  value=as.vector(t(x)))
```

Then you can plot it by building up the components you can see in the plot (points and lineranges; faceting, axis control and facet borders):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x=item,y=value,ymin=0,ymax=value)) + 
               geom_point(colour=I("blue"))       + 
               geom_linerange(colour=I("blue"))   + 
               facet_wrap(~draw,ncol=5)           + 
               scale_y_continuous(lim=c(0,1))     +
               theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill=0, colour="black"))
```

Output:
[image: Plot of Dirichlet draws]

Comment: (+1) Some example output would be very nice. A Dirichlet sample of dimension $d$ and sample size $n$ with $\alpha=1$ can be easily generated as follows: `pre.x <- matrix(rexp(n*d),n); x <- pre.x / rowSums(pre.x)`

Comment: @cardinal If you can post more explanation on why the above computation is equivalent to `rdirichlet`, it would be great.

Comment: @Anand, A [standard method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Related_distributions) for sampling from a general $\mathrm{Dir}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d)$ distribution is to generate independent $X_i \sim \Gamma(\alpha_i,1)$ random variables and then take $(X_1/S, \ldots, X_d/S)$ where $S = \sum_{i=1}^d X_i$. In the case where $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_d = 1$, then the $X_i$ are iid $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ random variables since a $\Gamma(1,1)$ variate is equivalent to an $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ one.

Comment: @Anand: My pleasure.